# Laravel morph relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I have a question regarding saving polymorphic relationships in Laravel. This is the model i would like to create in laravel.

[image: Class diagram]

A shop has many products, and a product can be either an "item" an "event" or a "service".

I have the following tables:

- shops

  - id
  - user_id
  - name
- events

  - id
  - public
  - title
  - description
- products

  - id
  - shop_id
  - productable_id
  - productable_type

This is how i set up the models:

```
class Shop extends Model{
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}

class Product extends Model{
    public function productable(){
        return $this->morphTo();   
    }
}

class Event extends Model{
    public function product(){
        return $this->morphOne('App\Product','productable');
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
$shop = Shop::first()
$event = Event::create(['title'=>'Some event']);
$service = Service::create(['title' => 'Some service']);
$shop->products()->save($event);
$shop->products()->save($service);
```

But it doesn't work! When i try to save the relation i get:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: shop_id (SQL: update "accendo_events" set "updated_at" = 2016-11-26 10:11:02, "shop_id" = 1 where "id" = 1)'
```

Anyone have an idea of where this is going wrong? I probably misunderstood something about this type of relationship...

Comment: try `$shop->products()->create($event);`

Comment: @Sherif that doesn't work either.. I get:
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::create() must be of the type array, object given on line 3

Comment: sorry we're not creating here. an event belongs to one product, so this syntax is wrong

Comment: you need to specofy a certain product then `$product->create($event);`

Comment: not sure though

Comment: @Sherif it's still not working.. I think something is wrong with my model setup.. But not sure what..

Comment: @Bisgaard Y are you creating an empty event/service? Are you trying to associate that empty event/service with all the products in the db?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all add a back relation to `Shop` from `Product` **Model**

```php
    class Shop extends Model
    {
      public function products()
      {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
      }
    }

    class Product extends Model
    {
      public function shop()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shop');
      }

      public function productable()
      {
        return $this->morphTo();
      }
    }

    class Event extends Model
    {
      public function product()
      {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Product', 'productable');
      }
    }
```

Now, I am not sure why you are trying to make an empty event and add it to all the products, but still if you want to do it for whatever use cases... please follow the below approach... :)

```
$shop = Shop::first();            //or $shop = Shop::find(1);

foreach($shop->products as $product) {
  $event = Event::create([]);
  $service = Service::create([]);

  $product->productable()->saveMany([
    $event, $service
  ]);
}
```

Let me know in the comments below if something doesn't work :)

### -- Edit

First of all, please understand that you can not add an entry to `productable_id` or `productable_type` from a `hasMany()` relation. You need to make sure you are using a `morph` relation for such purposes.

Secondly, since you are trying to add products first and not events first, the insertion method is not working out for you. Please note that you must try to create an **Event or Service first** and then try to associate with a shop.

The simplest approach to doing it would be

```
$shop = Shop::first();

$event = Event::create(['title' => 'Some Event']);
$event->product()->create(['shop_id' => $shop->id]);

$service = Service::create(['title' => 'Some Service']);
$service->product()->create(['shop_id' => $shop->id]);
```

You can also, try to follow my first approach, but the one I just mentioned is definitely supposed to work... and actually that is how it is meant to be inserted/created.

Comment: I don't really wanna create an empty event. I was just too lazy to write out the attributes.. :)

When i try your solution i get this error:
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:     Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: products.productable_id (SQL: insert into "products" ("shop_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (1, 2016-11-28 08:51:24, 2016-11-28 08:51:24))'

I try to save it like this:
$shop = Shop::first()
$product = new Product
$product->productable()->save(Event::create([]))
$shop->products()->save($product)

Comment: @Bisgaard Can you edit your question and make changes to it so I know what exactly you are trying? Also, please don't do `$product = new Product;` instead do `$product = Product::create([]);`. Let me know once you have edited your question.

Comment: @prateekkathal Why - "please don't do $product = new Product; instead do $product = Product::create([]);" ?

Comment: @cja According to the use-case, if you want to only create the item in PHP memory, then you can do `new Model()`, but otherwise, to create it into database and make use of relational queries, you must do `Model::create` instead.

Comment: @prateekkathal Either is fine. If you're using the constructor, you just need to remember to save your model when you're done setting the properties on it. It can be helpful to use the constructor in some cases, and there's no reason not to, if you feel like your code makes more sense that way.