# A model with polymolymorphic ony to many and simple one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I am using laravel 5.7. I have now a situation where i have a `Fight` model with structure `user_id, fightable_id`
i have two other tables `users` and `monsters`. so `users_id` refers to users (a user can have many fights) and `fightable_id` can refer to either a `user` or a `monster` (monsters table). so I have to define the functions for the relation ship

for User model i have to do

1.for polymorphic one to many relationship

```
public function fights()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Fight', 'fightable');
}
```

2.for simple one to many relationship

```
 public function fights()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Fight');
    }
```

I am confused now. ofcourse the only way is to change the functions name. but i will be doing the correct thing by changing the function names right (as both the functions have same name). or is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely but I'll try my best!

Also this post will really help you understand the problem you are facing I think,
[Laravel morph relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817211/laravel-morph-relationship)

Using the code from the post I linked but taking your tables would produce models defined like this.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function fights()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fight');
  }
}
```

**Fight Model**

```
class Fight extends Model
{
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

  public function fightable()
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

**Monster Model**

```
class Monster extends Model
{
  public function fight()
  {
    return $this->morphOne('App\Fight', 'fightable');
  }
}
```

If you still feel this has not answered your question or need some more help just let me know!