# Struggling with Laravel's morphable relationships

Tags: laravel

In a project, let's say that we have Customers, and each customer can have one Voucher. The voucher, though, may be for a different thing for different customers - maybe for a Hote, a Car or a Flight.

We have a table of flight voucher codes, a table of hotel voucher codes and a table of car voucher codes.

When a customer is allocated a voucher, therefore, we allocated them the next code for the relevant thing that they're getting a voucher for. But rather than have multiple tables (customer_car_voucher, customer_hotel_voucher, and so on) I would rather have a Voucher table which is, in turn, linked to the relevant voucher type.

What I want to be able to do is just go $customer->voucher->code to get the relevant code, whether that be a flight, a hotel or a car. Other vouchers may be added at a later date, you see, for different things.

I think I can do this using morphable relationships - the voucher morphsTo car, hotel and flight, so within the the voucher table there is a "voucherable_type" and a "voucherable_id". But damned if I can get it to work.

Any help, please? Am I going about it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you arte right. and for a hint use:

```
  public function customer()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class):
  }

  public function voucherable()
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
```

in voucher model.

and for each flight,car,hotel include:

```
public function voucher(){
    return $this->morphOne(Voucher::class,'voucherable');
}
```

you can see [Laravel morph relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817211/laravel-morph-relationship) too for more help.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel's Eloquent ORM is used for morphable relationships.

First, create two Models `AirVoucher` and `Voucher`.

First, the `AirVoucher` model uses the following relationship.

```
public function voucher()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Voucher::class, 'voucherable');
}
```

Second, the `Voucher` model uses the following relationship.

```
public function voucherable()
{
   return $this->morphTo();
}
```

You can use the following Laravel official relationship document for more help.

[Laravel Morph Relationships.](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

you must use laravel Polymorphic Relationships.

in `Voucher model` set this model as polymorph model(`function name = modelname+"able"`):

```
public function voucherable() \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

then in `Car model` (or hotel/fight) set realation(`function name= polymorph name`):

if each car has `one` voucher, use morphOne:

```
public function files(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne
{
    return $this->morphOne(Voucher::class, 'voucherable');
}
```

if each car has `many` voucher, use morphMany:

```
public function files(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Voucher::class, 'voucherable');
}
```

**Retrieving The Relationship**

```
$car = Car::find(1);
$vocher = $car->voucher;
```

[laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)